# Best choice to store large amounts of data in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I am currently developing a Windows Phone application which has to be ready to handle big amounts of data. Most of this data is going to be used as the data source for ListBox objects within the application.
I would like to know which would be the best approach to get the best performance, since I have opted for JSON, serializing objects and saving them to a .txt file, but the performance is far from being acceptable when the serialized objects contain big Lists/Arrays.

I have also considered a local database using LINQ to SQL, but I am not sure if it is possible to save Lists in the database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You may consider using binary serialization instead of JSON. If you need the whole list to be loaded at once, and you do not update the list frequently, then saving into a file is much faster.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try to use binary serialization and see what happens.

Comment: Is this all being saved in Isolated storage of on a server elsewhere?

Comment: I finally went for binary serialization. I am saving it in IsolatedStorage so it does not have to be "portable" (like JSON). The performance now is much better. Thank you!